# Get List of Directories Using Environment variable in Java

Tags: java, environment-variables

How can i get all files of my present Working Directory in Linux by using Environment variable(JAVA)?

Map env = pb.environment(); - I want to set Present Working Directory in this MAP as a Environment Variable.

Is it possible to get all list of directories by using this MAP?

Answer (score 0):

This question discussed before, please take a look at them before you raise a new one:

- [How to get current directory in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050131/how-to-get-current-directory-in-java)
- [Getting current working directory in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/getting-the-current-working-directory-in-java)

If above threads doesn't help, please do let us know what's the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question. Would you please check it again?