# Java CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, promise

I am Trying to read and write Extensible Linking Format (ELF) Below is the Line that I am getting Error.

```
p =  r.exec("./optimizer " + sourceFile + " " + sourceFile + "a" + " " + "--all -i");
```

After Running this line I am Getting Error Like :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./optimizer": CreateProcess             
error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
at GUIMode.GUIMode.actionPerformed(GUIMode.java:213)
```

Answer (score 6):

There a few possible causes for the "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" message including:

- the pathname for the application is incorrect,
- the file named by the pathname is not recognized by Windows as an executable, or
- the file is a 32 bit executable, but for some reason it is trying to load a 64 bit DLL.

In this case, you are using a relative pathname for the executable, so it is possible that the JVM's current directory is different to what you think ... and the `optimizer` file is not in that directory.

Try the following:

1. Replace `"./optimizer"` with an absolute pathname.
2. It the command (absolute) pathname or the `sourceFile` arguments contain spaces, replace the command string with an array of strings; e.g.

   ```
   exec(new String[]{
          "C:/path/to/optimizer",
          sourceFile, sourceFile + "a", "--all", "-i"});
   ```
3. Try running the command from the command prompt.  The idea is to check that this isn't caused by a non-executable file or a DLL problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your code is not running in the directory you think it is.

Use the OP's code given here: [how to get current directory in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14050131/98811)

```
File directory = new File (".");
try {
    System.out.println ("Current directory's canonical path: " 
            + directory.getCanonicalPath()); 
    System.out.println ("Current directory's absolute  path: " 
                + directory.getAbsolutePath());
}catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exceptione is ="+e.getMessage());
}
```

Now compare that to where optimizer is located.

Generally speaking, unless you control how the JVM is invoked, you can't rely on relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when running a `gradle` command in windows OS, but other OS ( linux, osx ) are not the problems.

I find the `gradle` is a `bat` script in windows OS finally , so need to add the suffix.

```java
    public Process callTestInSubprocess(Class<?> clazz, String testMethod) {
        String canonicalName = clazz.getCanonicalName();
        StringBuffer testCmd = new StringBuffer(isWinOS() ? "gradle.bat" : "gradle")
                .append(" testDebug -Psubprocess=true --tests ")
                .append(canonicalName)
                .append(".")
                .append(testMethod);

        return runSubprocess(testCmd.toString());
    }



    public static boolean isWinOS() {
        return System.getProperty("os.name", "generic").toLowerCase().indexOf("win") != -1;
    }
```