# How to execute a program from Java

Tags: java, autohotkey, executable, ioexception

I am trying to figure out how to execute my AutoHotKey script from my Java program. The issue is I am not sure the best way to actually do this because when I do this I get an error...

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        String actualPath = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Coding\\test.ahk";
        String autoHotKeyScript = "C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotkey";
        runtime.exec(new String[] {autoHotKey, actualPath});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With the error :

> Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Comment: Start by figuring out how you'd do something like this just from the commandline

Comment: Ok, some quick googling, you need to do something like `path_to/AutoHotKey.exe test.ahk`, but I'd investigate using `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec`, it will give you more control and options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50156510/java-createprocess-error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)

Comment: Gokul Nath KP that does not help me know it just tells me I have an issue which is nothing new.

Comment: @UnSure I'd recommend reading the [Java Docs for `Runtime.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).  You should seperate the commands into different elements (of an array), where the first element is the command to execute and other elements are the parameters you want to pass

Comment: MadProgrammer yes you are right I have updated it since then but I am not getting an access denied error. I went into the security settings of AutoHotKey but everything has access to read and execute so I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @UnSure Also, what is the exact path to, and including, `AutoHotKey.exe`.  I'd imagine it should be something like `C:/Program Files/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        runtime.exec("C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotkey.exe C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\Coding\\test.ahk");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

add the `AutoHotkeyU64.exe` before your ahk script.