# get file location from bean using getRealPath()

Tags: jsf, netbeans, primefaces, weblogic

I have a problem with accessing an external file from my back bean. What I would like to do is to use ttf file in order to use the font through iText library. When I run my application via Netbeans 7.2 the code below works fine:

```
private static String fontPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("arialuni.ttf");
```

But as I deploy my ear file manually through Oracle Weblogic 11g console, ttf file is not found and I get NullPointerException.

I have tried several ways to get it work but no chance. If someone could help me, I would be greatly appriciated.

Regards

Comment: Is shipping the ttf file in your JAR and getting it via [ClassLoader#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) an option?

Comment: Hi, I tried your way but doesn't seem to work again. But anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Where did you put your font file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ServletContext#getRealPath()` (and inherently thus also its JSF delegator `ExternalContext#getRealPath()`) will return `null` when the servletcontainer is configured to expand the deployed WAR in RAM memory space instead of in local disk file system space. "Heavy" servers are known to do that to improve performance. As there's no means of a physical local disk file system path which you could further utilize in `File` or `FileInputStream`, `null` will be returned.

The `getRealPath()` is absolutely the wrong tool for the purpose of obtaining the file's content. [Never ever use `getRealPath()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-method-servletcontext-getrealpath/12160863#12160863). You should be using `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream()` (or its JSF delegator `ExternalContext#getResourceAsStream()`) instead.

```
InputStream content = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("/arialuni.ttf");
// ...
```

Note that you should absolutely not assign the `InputStream` as a static variable for obvious reasons. If you really need to, read it into a `byte[]` first so that you can safely close it.

#### See also:

- [What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-method-servletcontext-getrealpath/)
- [Where to place and how to read configuration resource files in servlet based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app/)
- [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-)
- [How to save generated file temporarily in servlet based web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255366/how-to-save-generated-file-in-servlet-based-web-application)

Comment: Thanks for answer BalusC. I would like to use that font in:
BaseFont bfArialUniCode = BaseFont.createFont(content, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.CACHED). Is there any way to convert it string? Or should I override it via toString()?

Comment: In other words, the API you're working with doesn't accept an `InputStream` but only a `File` or a `String` representing its disk file system path? Well, just save the obtained `InputStream` to a temporary file which you create by `File#createTempFile()` and then pass it instead.

Comment: Exactly. I am working with iText. It only accepts the files or a system path. Btw, thanks for your great comments, sir.

Answer (score 1):

The relative path you pass to `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath()` method, must be relative to context path of your FacesServlet.

lets say you have the `"arialuni.ttf"` in your `resources` folder in FacesServlet context path, then you should pass `"/resources/arialuni.ttf"` to the `getRealPath()` method like below:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/resources/arialuni.ttf");
```

For details see this:

- [ExternalContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)
- [ServletContext#getRealPath()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)