# Relative URL to Absolute Path

Tags: java, jsp

what I am trying to do is to read content of html file. On click of a link the html file content should be read and that content will be used somwhere in my code.

**What I tried:**

I tried converting relative path to absolute path

```
String absoluteFilePath = servletContext.getRealPath("/html/en/TestPage.html");
```

and this works fine in **weblogic** on my **windows** dev machine but when this code is deployed to **webloic** on **Unix** machine the above code is returning null. I dig up google and I found

> "servletContext.getRealPath returns null if the servlet container cannot translate
>   the virtual path to a real path for any reason (such as when the
>   content is being made available from a .war archive)."

Can you please suggest best way to convert the relative path to absolute(using context path). The code should work on windows as well as on Unix platform or some other way round to read the html file like instead of reading from absolute path if I can read file file from relative path.

Comment: what server are you using? can you tell us the full qualified classname of servletcontext?

Comment: seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/2078908

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does "/" mean in the method 'servletcontext.getRealPath'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-mean-in-the-method-servletcontext-getrealpath)

Comment: 3 upvotes for a duplicate question . cant understand what is going on

Comment: @SanKrish If a duplicate question describes the same issue, but in different words, that can actually be a good thing (if someone is searching while debugging their issue and happens to use this different wording, that's someone who found what they needed and might not necessarily have before). It's the "search key phrase from question and immediately get several solutions as top hits" type questions that really shouldn't get upvotes.

Comment: I'll admit though, I don't have enough context to be 100% sure which of those this question falls under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `getRealPath(...)` if the war is exploded, but you can always **read** a file under servlet context root with `getResource(...)` or `getResourceAsStream(...)`. In your example, it will become :

```
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/html/en/TestPage.html");
```

And then you can safely read it ...