# FacesContext instance is null in ApplicationScoped Managedbean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, postconstruct, facescontext

I created a `ApplicationScoped` bean that have a `PostConstruct` method named start.
Whenever i want to get instance of `FacesContext` in the start method and it returns `null`:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class RemoveOldFilesScheduler implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    private void start() {
        final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(facesContext != null) {
            String realDownloadDirName = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRealPath("/") + DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        File downloadDir = new File(realDownloadDirName);
        if (downloadDir.exists()) {
            removeOldFiles(downloadDir.listFiles());
        }
}
}
```

How can i access to `facesContext` in this situation?

I want to get real path of my download directory in the start method and i don't know how to get path of my directory without using `FaceContext`.

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: What version of JSF are you running and in what container?

Comment: I am using latest version of jsf (2.2.8-02).

Comment: I had to implementing my class as `Listener` ,so i can access to `ServletContext` in `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`

Comment: You should use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getRealPath` http://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/892994

Comment: @erencan my `FacesContext` is null and can't access to it.

Comment: @ApplicationScpoed beans should be created with first request. I think, there is something initialized it in your configuration. Can you give the details of your web.xml

Comment: Since JSF 2.2(at least), you can use `@Inject` in a JSF managed bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implementing my class as `Listener` and it worked and i can access to `ServletContext` in `contextInitialized` method :

```
    public class RemoveOldFilesListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        String realDownloadDirName = servletContext.getRealPath("/") + DOWNLOAD_DIRECTORY;
        File downloadDir = new File(realDownloadDirName);
        if (downloadDir.exists()) {
            removeOldFiles(downloadDir.listFiles());
        }
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better and more logical way to do it, since the logic sits outside the JSF application proper (which it should)