# How to write on file having its url from a servlet

Tags: url, servlets, file-io, filestream

How can I write on a file having its URL such as `/WebContent/Database/myFile.json` from a Servlet?

Constraint: I can't use absolute paths to write on this file.

Additional info: the servlet receives a string as a POST parameter, then her should write this string on a file located in the same servlet context.

Comment: Should it be a permanent file or a temporary file? In any case, this answer should contain sufficient hints: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31255366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
It is a very bad idea to write files to the servlets context, [see this answer from @BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/2927457).

---

**Not recommended** But here is how you can get the absolute path for this context relative path

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
String relPath = "/WebContent/Database/myFile.json";
String absPath = context.getRealPath(relPath);
```