# Getting resource from ExternalContext in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

In my bean I am getting the URL of an image like this:

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
URL url = ec.getResource("/myImageDirectory/image.png");
```

How can I do this in a HttpServlet?

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
URL url = sc.getResource("/myImageDirectory/image.png");
```

The HttpServlet is in the same application as the bean.

Comment: Is image located in current app?

Comment: yes it is. I updated the question.

Comment: getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"myImageDirectory/image.png";

Comment: yes , what @Satya said is correct , but to confirm it first check the getServletContext() for which dir it is looking to get the resources , before appending the custom path

Comment: @Satya: Thanks. Works perfect. Please post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/myImageDirectory/image.png";
```

The "/" represents the web content root.

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"/myImageDirectory/image.png";