# How to return many HTML files together in Java servlet response?

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a few html files each of them containing the components of my future web page. I want them to be shown if user was looking for them. But how can I show many html files together in servlet response? As I know, the code below can redirect user to only one html file.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
response.sendRedirect("/index.html");
```

I tried to use IO streams:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/header.html")));
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.add(str);
    }
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    for (String item: content) {
        out.println(item);
    }
}
```

But it gives me only java.io.FileNotFoundException:header.html. Browser says: "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error".
How can I solve this? Should use another way?

Comment: Do you want to return several views in a single responde or want to trigger a download of the physical HTML files when the client fires the request?

Comment: The only way to send back multiple pages would be to tar or zip them. Typically, the way web browsing works is that the first query that goes out downloads an HTML file which may have other dependencies (images, javascript etc) which are requested once the initial html file arrives

Comment: You could use rd.include, but you will have the head tag many times, html files will be concatenated.

Comment: How exactly is "java.io.FileNotFoundException: header.html" unclear? Why exactly do you think that this specific problem is related to including multiple HTML files?

Answer (score 0):

Your `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is because of this `new FileInputStream("/header.html")`

You need the path to the file.

If it were a JSP that was reading the file:

```
new FileInputStream(application.getRealPath("/")+"header.html")
```

For a servlet, its slightly more complicated because you can't use `application` and rather need a variable with a `ServletContext` stored in it:

```
private ServletContext context;

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    this.context = config.getServletContext();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
   ....
   ....   new FileInputStream(context.getRealPath("/")+"header.html")
   ....
}
```

Comment: There's no need for a `FileInputStream` to obtain a web resource as an `InputStream`. Anytime you think to need `getRealPath()`, stop and ask  yourself if there isn't a better way. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it

Comment: @BalusC what makes that the case? I just tried `new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./WEB-INF/conf/config.xml"))` and `new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/WEB-INF/conf/config.xml"))` on a app I have and they don't work but `new BufferedReader(new FileReader(application.getRealPath("/")+"WEB-INF/conf/config.xml"))` does...so is this only to do with `FileInputStream` or its a Java version issue or what?

Comment: @BalusC The link does not answer the question I have