# Why does servletContext.getRealPath returns null on tomcat 8?

Tags: java, tomcat, path, tomcat8, servlet-container

I have the following code line:

```
servletContext.getRealPath("resources/images/video_icon.png")
```

Wen I run application using jetty(using maven plugin) this code line return corect value.

When I run application using tomcat 8(on tomcat 7 it works) - application returns null.

application structure:

[image]

1.How to fix it?
2.Why does it happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

after adding `/` in the path beginning it works for both: jetty and tomcat 8

```
servletContext.getRealPath("/resources/images/video_icon.png")
```

Comment: The reason is Tomcat requires / at the begining

Comment: Thanks Tangobee , Kindly let me know why tomcat 8 is doing this or you can why this thing is changed. There might be some reason behind this I am investigating that thing.