# System.getProperty("mode") returns "null"

Tags: java, tomcat, properties

We recently had to set up one of the tomcat servers from scratch. Tomcat version is 8.0.20. Deploying a war file, now `System.getProperty("mode")` returns "null" where it should return PREPROD.

It should read this "mode" from a mode.properties file which is located in the webapps directory. The two lines commented out show another part of code that does not work anymore on the new tomcat server. I replaced it with code that should work.

```
//String pathOfWebInf = sce.getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF");
//String pathOfLocalhostFile = pathOfWebInf + File.separator + "classes"
//      + File.separator;
String pathOfLocalhostFile = this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath();

String mode = System.getProperty("mode");
String fileName = "localhost-oracle.properties." + mode;

StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
encryptor.setPassword("xxx");

Properties dbProps = new EncryptableProperties(encryptor);
try
{
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pathOfLocalhostFile + fileName);
    dbProps.load(is);
} catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new IOException("Could not read properties file " + pathOfLocalhostFile + fileName);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest putting your properties into catalina.properties in the servers /conf folder.

Comment: I solved the problem by reverting to Tomcat 7, Tomcat 8 had issues like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197494/why-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-returns-null-on-tomcat-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load mode.properties first, like this way

```
private Properties mode=null;
mode = new Properties();
mode.load(new FileInputStream(pathtoMODE));

String mode = mode.getProperty("mode");
```

Comment: Ideally I would not have to hardcode a path, maybe it should check the class path for properties files. Also I would like to make a minimum set of changes to the code and the configuration, as the "old" code is working on "old" tomcats in the deployment chain.

Answer (score 2):

**System.properties** is related to all properties in the Computer where the JVM is running... there is no **mode** key defined there, that is why you get null as value....

check out all the properties in the pc by doing:

```
final Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.list(System.out);
```

and verify yourself, there is no **mode** key in that map...

Comment: My question then would be: What can I change so that it reads properties from the webapps/mode.properties file like it did on the old tomcat?