# Servlet relative path "Path not found"

Tags: java

I'm trying to save files to my folder 'ProfileImages' which resides in WebContent/

When I run with below path I'm getting file not found exception

```
String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");

String savePath = appPath + "WebContent" + File.separator + "ProfileImages";

System.out.println(appPath + "WebContent" + File.separator + "ProfileImages");
```

print gives:

```
C:\Users\me\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Test\WebContent\ProfileImages\image.jpg (path not found)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to put "WebContent" folder in save path since , passing the "/" to getRealPath() would return you the absolute disk file system path of the /web folder of the expanded WAR file of the project

```
String savePath = appPath +  File.separator + "ProfileImages";
```

See also

[What does servletcontext.getRealPath(“/”) mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it)

Comment: Thanks, I'll just stick to using absolute path when testing. But it worked when I deploy it as war.