# IntelliJ IDEA not finding files for Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a WebServices REST project with IntelliJ IDEA. The idea is to supply some files to the user, but it seems that I can't find them in Tomcat's directory. For now I am trying to serve just a simple index.html page, but Java reports that the file could not be found. My current project structure is this: 
 [image: project structure]
I thought that any data should be in the WEB-INF folder, or have I put it in the wrong place? Also, this is my GET function with the class I'm using: 
[image] 
Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: I can't tell how you're doing your mapping, but the file is located under the servlet context root, not relative to the working directory of your web app.

Comment: I'm still learning how to do this, however my final aim is to have a personal REST server that I can perform tests on. As for the context root, how can I access that, or move the files there?

Comment: Share the url, u r trying to hit and also you have not mapped your url with the function, you need to use @ Path annotation

Comment: I am hitting http://localhost:9998/ , the path is @Path("/") , which is specified at the beginning of the class name. This class has only one method, loadHTML(), the one I posted above. I probably should have screenshot the whole class so it doesn't confuse you, will edit the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12160639/438992 But again, you're doing a lot of manual work that doesn't really seem necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the link, fixed it now! I am still toying with this and I am a complete beginner, so what part of the code seems unnecessary?

Comment: You're doing everything the hard way. Try following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: @EngineerDollery Thank you! If I am using an Android application, would I add the Spring for Android dependency in Gradle, and then build a Spring REST client with it?

Comment: The rest server has nothing to do with the android client and doesn't need to know anything about it at all, so don't add spring for android to the server component at all.