# Java Application Server working directory

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jboss

I have a java web service (.war file) that I deploy to a few different environments, namely Apache Tomcat 7.0.x and JBoss EAP 6.1.x. When I open a `File` object (`File file = new File("./test.file");`), the absolute path is different based on which application server I am using. I output the absolute path by calling `file.getAbsolutePath()`.

For Tomcat, it appears to look for `test.file` in the `Tomcat/bin` directory, but for my instance of JBoss EAP, it looks for `/test.file`, i.e. system root.

Is there some configuration parameter or environment variable for either of these two application servers that dictates the working directory?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat uses CATALINA_HOME,
I don't know much about JBoss,
but I think that uses EAP_HOME and JBOSS_HOME

Comment: I think you're right about CATALINA_HOME, perhaps with a 'bin/' appended to it, based on what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The working directory in a webapp is relative to the servlet context.

And its correct. The getAbsolutePath method returns to you the corresponding path for the path give into

see here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()

or here for example

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-filepath-of-a-file-in-java/

But, if do you want the path absolute to the current webapp then you can try this one:

[What does servletcontext.getRealPath("/") mean and when should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it)