# List all files inside resource directory Jersey servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jersey

I'm trying to retrieve all the files inside a resources folder to be able to use it on `JAXB` unmarshaller, but i could'nt find anything that i could use instead of the regular `file.listFiles()` on java.

I've tried `File files = new File(this.context.getResource("/WEB-INF/folder").getPath());` and use it on a foreach loop, but a null pointer was thrown.

Just to point it out, context is a Jersey `@Context ServletContext context` injected variable.

**@Update**

Ok, im using `getResourcePaths` now and converting each path to uri and than to file.

```
Set<String> catalogosPath = this.context.getResourcePaths("/WEB-INF/catalogos/");
        for(String catalogoPath : catalogosPath){
            URI uri = context.getResource(catalogoPath).toURI();
            File arquivo = new File(uri.getPath());
            tempCat = (Catalogo) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(arquivo);
            catalogos.add(tempCat);
        }
```

Than tomcat is throwing me an error, it says that the file `/localhost/cvrest/WEB-INF/catalogos/myfile.xml` Doesnt exist but it **exist**. I'm trying to unmarshall it but it keeps me throwing no file found.  I might be missunderstanding the return from getresourcepaths, it gives me an url, am i converting it right?

Comment: Whatever answer you get, NEVER use `getRealPath()`, just use `getResourcePaths()`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/12160639

Comment: @BalusC I wasn't aware of that. I've updated my answer to use `getResource()`.

Comment: @Cássio: you're still treating them as local disk file system paths. As said, use `getResourcePaths()` and do in no way convert them to `File`/`Path`. It are not per definition files. Those can reside in memory or virtual file system or even somewhere else in network (in other words, URI doesn't guaranteed start with `file://`)

Comment: @BalusC Makes sense.

Comment: @BalusC i've updated the question.

Comment: You should not be attempting to interpret them as local disk file system paths. Just use `getResourceAsStream()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `context.getRealPath("/")` inside your servlet to get the base path of your project. To get the list of files just append your file path relative to your project path, for example, `context.getRealPath("/") + "/WEB-INF/classes/folder`