# File Not Found at given file path in Java Servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets, filereader

I am trying to read json data from a file I have in my `WebContent` folder, **not** my `WEB-INF` folder. Everything works when I use an absolute file path, but if I use another method to get the file path, the Java `FileReader` cannot find the file.

I am using a Java `FileReader`.

I have also tried using the below code, but it doesn't work:
`String JSON_FILE = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("users.json");`

Also, when I type in: users.json    , after the base url, I can see the json data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with `getRealPath("/users.json");` Anw, `getResourceAsStream`  are recommended. Please refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it

Comment: Yes, I have. I also tried getClass().getResource()