# Why tomcat 8 required / at the beginning of ServletContext.getRealPath()

Tags: tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

If I use this **

> servletContext.getRealPath(""resources/images/video_icon.png")

** It doesn't work in tomcat 8 but just adding the / at the beginning it works fine in tomcat 8.

***So I just want to know why tomcat 8 is doing this. If tomcat guys has changed the behaviour so there might be some reason behind this.***

Any comment guys ?

Comment: On windows is changed, i have the same problem.

Comment: this may help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160639/what-does-servletcontext-getrealpath-mean-and-when-should-i-use-it