# How to inject a ServletContext outside of CDI lifecycle

Tags: java, jax-rs, wildfly

I need access to the ServletContext to use the getRealPath() method on some files that are in my WEB-INF directory. However, the class I need to do this work in is a non-CDI class that is used for some backend processing based on a request made earlier from JAX-RS. How can I get the ServletContext outside of the lifecycle of the JAX-RS request?

I'm using Wildfly 10, if that changes the way I would go about this

Comment: What do you mean for backend processing? Ejb?

Comment: I honestly don't know. This is pretty new to me.

The request goes into a queue to be processed by a separate thread later and the REST call just returns 200 to say it'll be in the queue. But I need the ServletContext on the other thread, after the REST call has returned, to perform the operation scheduled from the request on a file inside the WAR's WEB-INF. But since it's on a separate thread and the JAX-RS call has already returned, the ServletContext, even though it was put in the queue as well, is now null.

Comment: `getRealPath()` is unportable and you must not use it. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/1426227).

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to load a servlet at the startup of the Java EE application, see `@WebServlet` annotation. The `Servlet.init()` method is invoked upon startup of the container, which we will leverage to work with `ServletContext`, in this case calling `getRealPath()` and storing returned value into static variable. You may access the value from the rest of your app by calling `RealPathServlet.getRealPath()`.

```
@WebServlet(value="/real-path", loadOnStartup=1)
public class RealPathServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static String realPath;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        realPath = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("yolo");
        Logger.getLogger(ContextPathServlet.class.getName()).info("Real path is " + realPath);
    }

    public static getRealPath() {
        return realPath;
    }

    ...
}
```