# Spring MVC - Copy image into WEB-INF/assets folder

Tags: image, spring-mvc, copy

I am trying to copy image into assets folder inside **WEB-INF** folder. Following code successfully copy images outside the project but can't copy inside WEB-INF folder.

```
public static void copyFile(String source, String destination) throws IOException {
        try {
            File sourceFile = new File(source);
            File destinationFile = new File(destination);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

            int bufferSize;
            byte[] bufffer = new byte[512];
            while ((bufferSize = fileInputStream.read(bufffer)) > 0) {
                fileOutputStream.write(bufffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I get a image path from `Http` request.

```
CopyFile.copyFile(imageUrl, "http://localhost:8080/M.S.-Handloom-Fabrics/static/"+imageName+".png");
```

I have mapped the resources in **dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/assets/"/>
```

Here is the error

> Info:   http:\localhost:8080\M.S.-Handloom-Fabrics\static\TueJun1216_27_54NPT20180.png (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:8080/M.S.-Handloom-Fabrics/static/"+imageName+".png"
```

is a URL, not a file-path, and is therefore meaningless as a parameter to the File constructor.

IF you configured your app server to explode your webapp on deploy then you could use `ServletContext.getRealPath` but as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12160863/5609837) details nicely you most likely do not want to do this as your saved files will be lost upon re-deploy.

Saving them outside of the web app is the way to go.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestion about how to use `ServletContext.getRealPath`. If you have a time please correct my above code. Thanks

Comment: I can try.  You need access to the http request.  Where is this copyFile method called from?  A servlet?  A Spring @Controller?  Or ???